# How to create a button matrix in wpf with mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I need to create a datagrid that look like a matrix,
The matrix display buttons for each day and its 24 hours.
somthing like:
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
             0
             1
             .
             .
             23
I am using MVVM pattern that seems to make it harder to implement,
thank you all.

Comment: with `MVVM` you do not create an interface, but create link between UI and data. What is you problem here ?

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how to connect between a matrix collection and my xmal to present a datagrid as i described.

Comment: with `listview` I can give you a hand

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DaysOfWeek}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HoursInDay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This assumes you have a collection called `DaysOfWeek` in your data context (ie. in your main view model). Each `DayOfWeek` object would expose an `HoursInDay` collection (likely the same shared collection).

Having said all that, what is the advantage to data-driving this? Is your matrix likely to change in dimensions? If not, why not just "hard-code" the matrix in your view? Each matrix cell can still bind to an appropriate data item in your view model.

Comment: Thank you very much. may you explain to me how can i do it hard - coded.

Comment: Actully i prefer binding cell to an appropriate  in my view model, i just dont know how to do that...